# How to Create a Table like the below

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have created a TableView(Grouped Table View). And I can list the items in the table view. But I want to know how the below table is displayed[image]

Like Calender is in the left side, and Gregorian in the Right Side ?? How that Gregorian is displayed in the Right Side ??  Is it a Custom TableView, Can anyone help me how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are just regular cells with `style = UITableViewCellStyleValue1` and also `accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`.

To make one programmatically:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

(Note that in real life you would probably try to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, and only create a new cell if that returns nil.)

Or, if you're working with IB, set "Style" to "Right Detail" and "Accessory" to "Disclosure Indicator".

Comment: Style is coming, but how to display the second text such as India,Gregorian ??

Comment: `cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"like, whatever"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use following code helping to you

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        UIImageView *v = [[[UIImageView alloc] init]autorelease];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // put clear color
        [v setClipsToBounds:YES];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
        [cell setClipsToBounds:YES];
    }
    UIImageView *imgVBG=(UIImageView*)[cell selectedBackgroundView];
    if(indexPath.row==0){
        imgVBG.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopImg.png"];
    } else if((indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==4)||(indexPath.section==1 && indexPath.row==7)){
        imgVBG.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"BottomImg.png"];
    } else {
        imgVBG.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"MiddleImg.png"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the first 6 lines of this have any relevance to the question, and those are no different to what Yuji has posted already.

Comment: @jrurton  :But in different code is use for more efficient your uitableview so it's here

Answer (score -2):

Here is your answer [UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyleValue1, adding new line to detailTextLabel at cell at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933111/uitableviewcell-with-uitableviewcellstylevalue1-adding-new-line-to-detailtextla)