# iOS 8 UITableView placing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

With iOS 8 I have come up with some issues using **UITableView**. In fact, I have a NavigationController and its RootController set as my ViewController with **UITableView**. Then I configure my table, add cells and set their style to **UITableViewCellStyleValue1** and nothing happens at the time it should display a detailed text label to the right of the textLabel. I suppose that there is some missing constraints preventing from displaying the whole cell's view.

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"STI";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = self.dwarves[indexPath.row];
    cell.detailedLabel.text = @"Detailed text";

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star"];
    cell.imageView.image = img;

    return cell;
}
```

What I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I use for setting up my detailed text:

```
if (indexPath.row < 7) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"First";
} else {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Second";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the property you're looking for is `cell.detailTextLabel`, not `cell.detailedLabel`.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933111/uitableviewcell-with-uitableviewcellstylevalue1-adding-new-line-to-detailtextla).

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of updating an old app for iOS 8 and ran into the same issue. I haven't discovered the root of the problem yet, but calling `layoutSubviews` for the cell before returning it fixed it for me.

```
  ...

  [cell layoutSubviews];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I got realized what was the reason. All because of the new way Xcode 6 follows. You should make your table view the same height and width as the controller's view.